# Error happens when keeping an `ActorHandler` in another actor for later use

Tags: python, ray

I want a remote class to keep another remote class so that it can invoke it later. The following code provide an example

```py
import ray

ray.init()
@ray.remote
class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.l = None

    def set(self, learner):
        self.l = learner

    def step(self):
        x = ray.get(self.l.p.remote(self.a))
        return x

@ray.remote
class Learner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3

    def step(self, worker):
        print(ray.get(worker.step.remote()))

    def p(self, a):
        return a + self.a

l = Learner.remote()
w = Worker.remote()
w.set.remote(l)
ray.get(l.step.remote(w))
ray.shutdown()
```

However, this code does not work; it gets stuck without emitting any error. I know the source of the problem comes from the `step` function in `Worker`, but I don't know why it is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that `ray.get` is a blocking call. This means that your program will be blocked and cannot go to the next line of code until `ray.get` function is succeeded. (You can prevent this by adding a `timeout` argument to `remote` function).

This happens because `l` is blocked until `worker.step.remote` is done (`ray.get(worker.step.remote()`). When `worker.step` method is called, it tries to call `l.p.remote`. `w` will blocked until `l.p` is done because of `ray.get(self.l.p.remote(self.a)`. But as you can see, `l` is blocked and cannot run any code. It means that `l.p` will never run until `l.step` is done. Here is a simple diagram for your understanding.

[image]

Now both workers are blocked and `l.step.remote` will never be done. That means your driver (Python script) is also blocked.

As a result, the whole program is hang!!

Then how to solve this problem?

Firstly, I highly discourage you to use the pattern that two actor classes are waiting for each other. This is generally a bad pattern even when you are writing other programs. This can be solved when programs are multi-threaded or asynchronous.

If you really need to use this pattern, you can use the async actor. Async actor uses `await` instead of `ray.get`, and each actors are not blocked because they are running as coroutine.

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_api.html

EX)

```py
import ray

ray.init()
@ray.remote
class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.l = None

    def set(self, learner):
        self.l = learner

    async def step(self):
        x = await self.l.p.remote(self.a)
        return x

@ray.remote
class Learner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3

    async def step(self, worker):
        print(await worker.step.remote())

    async def p(self, a):
        return a + self.a

l = Learner.remote()
w = Worker.remote()
w.set.remote(l)
await l.step.remote(w)
# ray.shutdown()
```